# Prove that continued fractions are fractional linear transformations

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Consider the continuous fractions defined inductively by

$a_1=1+\frac{1}{x}, a_2=1+\cfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}, a_3=1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}, ...$

Prove that each $a_n$ is a fractional linear transformation, that is

$a_n=\frac{b_nx+c_n}{g_nx+h_n}$

and find the coefficients $b_n, c_n, g_n, h_n$. Then prove that

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{b_nx+c_n}{g_nx+h_n}=\frac{bx+c}{gx+h}$

and find $b, c, g, h$.

Please help, I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Work out $a_1, a_2, a_3$.  See what the coefficients are in that case.  Maybe you can guess a pattern (for an induction proof).  (If this problem is from a book, I suspect that the coefficients you get will be some numbers recently discussed in that book.)

Comment: Take the ansatz $a_n = \frac{xb_n + c_n}{xg_n + h_n}$ and plug it into the recurence $a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{a_n}$ to get that $b,c,g,h$ all satisfy the Fibonacci recurence $x_{n+1} = x_n + x_{n-1}$ (with different initial conditions).

Comment: @GEdgar - I was just working on that, and I see the pattern is the Fibonacci numbers. For example, $a_4 = \frac{f_4+f_3}{f_3+f_2}$, when using $f_0=1, f_1=1, f_2=2, ...$ This leads me to think that $b_n = f_n, c_n = f_{n-1}, g_n = f_{n-1}, h_n = f_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(F_n)_{n\ge0}$ be the Fibonacci sequence defined by $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$. Then it is an easy induction to show that
$$a_n=\frac {F_{n+ 2}x+F_{n+1}}{F_{n+1}x+F_n}=\frac {\frac{F_{n+ 2}}{ F_{n+1}}x+1}{x+\frac{ F_n}{ F_{ n+1}}}$$
Now, since it is well-known that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{F_{ n+1}}{F_n}=\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$
We conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac{\varphi x+1}{ x+1/\varphi}=\varphi$$ 
Which is independant of $x$.

Comment: I know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\phi$, however, why is it that $\frac{F_{n+2}x+F_{n+1}}{F_{n+1}x+F_n}=\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$? I don't see how the $x$ can just disappear.

Comment: @Michelle, hope, it is clarified now.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes it clear. I have been staring at this problem for so long that I could not see the intermediate step where you divided both the numerator and the denominator by $F_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Think Fibonacci.
$$
1 + \frac{1}{\frac{bx+c}{gx+h}} = 
\frac{\frac{(b+g)x + (c+g)}{gx + h}}{\frac{bx+c}{gx+h}} =
\frac{(b+g)x + (c+g)}{bx + c}
$$